# Laravel Eloquent not getting attribute set by default

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

My Eloquent migration contains a default value for a column, and that default value is indeed being set in the database when the model is created. However, Eloquent does not seem to know about this value and returns null.

The migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->increments('id');
       $table->string('name');
       $table->string('email')->unique();
       $table->string('password');
       $table->integer('role')->default(0);
       $table->rememberToken();
       $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

In the database, the value for role is indeed 0, but when calling `$user->getAttributes()` the `role` column does not even exist (likely because somehow the value is being set to null).

What am i missing to make this work? How can I properly set a default value that is actually usable?

Answer (score 1):

I can only guess, but I think you have also created `role` relationship for your `User` model, that's why you are getting null. You should never use same name for column and relationship and if any field is in fact foreign key to other table you should add sufix for primary key for this table, so for example here it would be recommended to use:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->increments('id');
       $table->string('name');
       $table->string('email')->unique();
       $table->string('password');
       $table->unsignedInterger('role_id')->nullable()->default(null);
       $table->rememberToken();
       $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

As you see above some extra changes could be made here to this column type.

Comment: actually, I have not created any relationships. I have actually done nothing after my fresh install of laravel other than `artisan make:auth` and added this field to the migration.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the default Laravel user migration and model, add the 'role' column as mass assignable in your User model

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password', 'role'];
```